# Como fazer uma função no Javascript que recebe um DataTable como parâmetro?

Tags: javascript, mvc, jquery-datatables

Olá

Fiz uma função genérica no JavaScript que precisa receber um DataTable como parâmetro, mas por alguma razão ela não está pegando os dados deste DataTable.

Essa função é chamada quando o usuário clica na célula do DataTable

```
$('#tableBaseHour').on('click', 'tbody td', function () {
    ClickTables('#tableBaseHour', $('#tableBaseHour thead th').length);
});
```

Eu terei ao todo 12 DataTables numa mesma tela, então por este motivo preciso de uma função genérica que pegue apenas o id do DataTable e faça a função. A função é esta:

```
function ClickTables(clickTable, lengthCols) {
var table = $(clickTable).DataTable();

var colIndex = table.column($(this).closest('td')).index();

var rowclicked = table.row($(this).closest('td')).index();

//SE A LINHA CLICADA NÃO ESTÁ DENTRO DA ÁREA DE CAMPOS QUANTITIES
if (table.rows().count() == table.row($(this).closest('tr')).index() ||
    colIndex == lengthCols - 1 || colIndex == 0 || rowclicked == 12) {
    return;
}
//SE A CÉLULA CLICADA ESTÁ DENTRO DA ÁREA DE CAMPOS QUANTITIES E É HABILITADA À EDIÇÃO
else {
    var row = table.row($(this).closest('tr')).index();
    //ABRE A MODAL DE EDIÇÃO DO CAMPO
    $('#newBHUnit').modal('show');
    $('#YearId').prop('disabled', true);
    $('#Month').prop('disabled', true);
    $("#InputTypeId").prop('disabled', true);
    $("#AnalyzeTypeId").prop('disabled', true);
    $("#LowTierId").prop('disabled', true);

    //CHAMA A FUNÇÃO QUE REALIZA O EDIT
    EditBaseHour(table.column(colIndex).title, $('#findYearBH').val(), row + 1);
}
}
```

Esta função está pegando as informações do campo, jogando para uma Modal e permitindo a edição do registro nela.

Quando a função estava aplicada diretamente dentro do *on click* funcionava perfeitamente, mas por alguma razão dentro do método ela não funciona (os dados passados no Edit que dependem das informações do DataTable passam nulos e a função do Edit não é realizada).

Alguém poderia me ajudar nisso?

Comment: usando o "onclick" podemos utilizar o "$(this)" , porém em uma função genérica não faz referência ao objeto clicado e sim aos parâmetros passados.

Comment: Era isso mesmo que estava dando problema, passei o que estava sendo referenciado pelo this como parâmetro para a função e funcionou. Obrigado!